# Flutter crashes on iPhone while processing large file

Tags: json, iphone, flutter

Upon startup of my Flutter app, I'm processing a large, deeply nested json file (for reference, the file is ~50mb) and placing it into a Trie. When building the Trie, the app stalls, then crashes. I think it may be some memory issue, either heap overflow or stack overflow.

What is the limit to the heap or stack while using flutter and running it on an iPhone X?

Does anyone know what could be causing this crash issue while processing my asset json file or what could fix it? Thanks!